# How can I build a mongoDB query to find any of myArray ids inside a document field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have on a mongoDB, a collection with the following schema:

```
const ReceiptSchema = new Schema(
  {
    status: String,
    active: Boolean,
    name: String,
    companies: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    total: Number
  },
  { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
)
```

And I have on my script the following ids Array:

```
myArray = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

How can I build a query to get all the documents fro Receipt schema that contains some of the ids on my array, inside the field **companies** ?

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Or to add a Schema.methods to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$setIntersection` to find any matching array element in companies array

on mongo 3.6+

find

```
db.recip.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : {$setIntersection : ["$companies", ['abc']]}}, 0] }})
```

aggregate

```
db.recip.aggregate(
    [
        {$match : {$expr : {$gt : [{$size : {$setIntersection : ["$companies", ['abc']]}}, 0] }}}
    ]
)
```

on mongo 3.4

```
db.recip.aggregate(
    [
        {$addFields : {isMatches : {$gt : [{$size : {$setIntersection : ["$companies", ['abc']]}}, 0] }}},
        {$match : {isMatches : true}}
    ]
)
```

change `$addFields` to `$project` in mongo version less than 3.4

Comment: This is exactlly what I need it! Thanks @Saravana